# Proof of income for UK visitor visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, business-travel

I am a Russian citizen who is invited to do a job interview at a company in London. The company will pay for my travels, accommodation, visa fees and have provided an invitation letter (which clearly also states that). For this, I need to get a visa for the UK.

Since I'm not yet employed, I can't provide a letter which states my regular income. However, it is the main requirement for the application process for a Standard Visitor Visa.

Instead, I could attach a letter showing the amount of money I have on my bank account. I read many times that it is often the reason for refusal that the source of income is not specified.

What would be the best option for me in this case? Will it be enough to show a copy of recent transactions, along with the invitation letter?

Comment: How are you supporting yourself currently if not via employment? e.g. are family members supporting you or are you living off savings from a previous job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The company advertising the vacancy will need to have UK government approval to sponsor work visas and should therefore be able to offer you advice on this. Alternatively, could you interview via Skype or another video link?

Comment: What do you mean by UK government approval? It is a British company which has provided such a letter already. The question is if this is enough as proof of funds.

Comment: UK companies can only offer work visa sponsorship if they cannot fill a vacancy with an EU worker, normally this means people with very specific skills. The government has a list of companies here https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/register-of-licensed-sponsors-workers . These companies will have knowledge of the visa process for recruiting international staff and can advise you

Comment: They will be interested in the source of your savings, so it would be beneficial to show them several months' worth (6+ months) of bank statements so that they can see the money hasn't just been deposited in your account recently.